# Cypher Query for neo4j to get the desired traversal

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am Modifying the Question so that it can be easily tested

Graph being used for testing

[image]

Green Nodes are Organizations and Blue Nodes are Person. Here is the script to create this graph:

```
CREATE (A:Organization {PRID:'A', Name:'Organization-A'})
CREATE (B:Organization {PRID:'B', Name:'Organization-B'})
CREATE (C:Organization {PRID:'C', Name:'Organization-C'})
CREATE (D:Organization {PRID:'D', Name:'Organization-D'})
CREATE (E:Organization {PRID:'E', Name:'Organization-E'})
CREATE (F:Organization {PRID:'F', Name:'Organization-F'})
CREATE (G:Organization {PRID:'G', Name:'Organization-G'})
CREATE (H:Organization {PRID:'H', Name:'Organization-G'})
CREATE (I:Organization {PRID:'I', Name:'Organization-I'})


CREATE (P1:Person {PRID:'P1', Name:'Person-P1'})
CREATE (P2:Person {PRID:'P2', Name:'Person-P2'})
CREATE (P3:Person {PRID:'P3', Name:'Person-P3'})
CREATE (P4:Person {PRID:'P4', Name:'Person-P4'})
CREATE (P5:Person {PRID:'P5', Name:'Person-P5'})
CREATE (P6:Person {PRID:'P6', Name:'Person-P6'})

CREATE
  (B)-[:CONTROL]->(A),
  (C)-[:CONTROL]->(A),
  (D)-[:CONTROL]->(C),
  (E)-[:CONTROL]->(C),
  (G)-[:CONTROL]->(F),
  (H)-[:CONTROL]->(F),

  (D)-[:EMPLOYS]->(P1),
  (P1)-[:SPOUSE]->(P2),
  (P2)-[:CONSULTS]->(E),

  (B)-[:EMPLOYS]->(P3),
  (P3)-[:SPOUSE]->(P4),
  (P4)-[:CONSULTS]->(I),

  (H)-[:EMPLOYS]->(P5),
  (P5)-[:SPOUSE]->(P6)
;
```

I am trying to write a cypher query that needs to accomplish the following:

a) Start with a Node with PRID = 'C' 
b) Path p1 = All the nodes connected to starting node with relationship types CONTROL (recursively) - irrespective of direction 
c) Path p2= optionally match the following relationship pattern 
              (x1)-[:EMPLOYS]->()-[:SPOUSE]->()-[:CONSULTS]->(x2) 
where (x1) and (x2) are nodes from the path p1 - found in step (b).

Return p1 and p2

Till now have tried the following three queries (with Brian's help)

```
Query1:
MATCH p1=(x:Organization {PRID: 'C'})-[r:CONTROL*]-(y)
OPTIONAL MATCH p2=(node1)-[:EMPLOYS]->()-[:SPOUSE]->()-[:CONSULTS]->(node2)
WHERE node1 in nodes(p1) and node2 in nodes(p1)
RETURN p1,p2;

Quesry2:
MATCH p1=(x:Organization {PRID: 'C'})-[r:CONTROL*]-(y)
WITH p1, nodes(p1) AS p1_nodes
UNWIND p1_nodes AS node1
UNWIND p1_nodes AS node2
WITH p1, node1, node2
OPTIONAL MATCH p2=(node1)-[:EMPLOYS]->()-[:SPOUSE]->()-[:CONSULTS]->(node2)    
WHERE p2 IS NOT NULL
RETURN p1, p2;

Query3:
MATCH p1=(x:Organization {PRID: 'C'})-[r:CONTROL*]-(y)
WITH p1, EXTRACT(node IN nodes(p1) | ID(node)) AS p1_node_ids
UNWIND p1_node_ids AS id1
UNWIND p1_node_ids AS id2
OPTIONAL MATCH p2=(node1)-[:EMPLOYS]->()-[:SPOUSE]->()-[:CONSULTS]->(node2)
WHERE ID(node1) = id1 AND ID(node2) = id2 AND p2 IS NOT NULL
RETURN p1, p2;
```

What I'd Expect is to get back the subgraph with nodes A, B, C, D, E,P1,P2 with the relationships, however all three just give me just A, B, C, D, E with the relationships (that is just p1, nothing from p2)

Some more queries we tried that work with some anchor nodes but not with any of the node in the first hierarchy

```
Query-4
MATCH p1=(x:Organization {PRID: 'C'})-[r:CONTROL*]-(y)
WITH collect({path: p1, node: y}) AS paths_and_nodes
UNWIND paths_and_nodes AS paths_and_node1
UNWIND paths_and_nodes AS paths_and_node2
WITH
  paths_and_node1.node AS node1,
  paths_and_node2.node AS node2,
  paths_and_node1.path AS path1,
  paths_and_node2.path AS path2
OPTIONAL MATCH p2=(node1)-[:EMPLOYS]->()-[:SPOUSE]->()-[:CONSULTS]->(node2)
RETURN path1, path2, p2, node1, node2
```

This one works with the x being specified as A, B or C. BUT Does not work if x points to D or E

```
Query 5
MATCH
  p1=(org1)-[:CONTROL*]-(x:Organization {PRID: 'C'})-[:CONTROL*]-(org2)
OPTIONAL MATCH p2=(org1)-[:EMPLOYS]->()-[:SPOUSE]->()-[:CONSULTS]->(org2)
RETURN p1, p2, org1, org2
```

This one works with the x being specified as C,D or E. BUT Does not work if x points to A or B

One thought - so if we have the query as

```
MATCH p1=(x:Organization {PRID: 'E'})-[r:CONTROL*]-(y)
OPTIONAL MATCH p2=(node1)-[:EMPLOYS]->()-[:SPOUSE]->()-[:CONSULTS]->(node2)
WHERE node1.PRID in ['A','B','C','D','E'] AND 
      node2.PRID in ['A','B','C','D','E']
RETURN p1,p2;
```

then it obviously works fine. So cant we somehow using COLLECT etc create this array and pass it to the next query. The problem seems to be - if after the first match i use 
 WITH p1, COLLECT (y.PRID) AS p1_prids 
  the p1_prids is not ['A','B','C','D','E'] but rather a multi row collection with just one element each

One way i could make it work consistently is

```
MATCH (x:Organization {PRID: 'C'})-[r:CONTROL*0..]-(y)
WITH COLLECT (y.PRID) AS p1_prids
MATCH p1=(x:Organization {PRID: 'C'})-[r:CONTROL*0..]-(y)
WITH p1,p1_prids
OPTIONAL MATCH p2=(node1)-[:EMPLOYS]->()-[:SPOUSE]->()-[:CONSULTS]->(node2)
WHERE node1.PRID in p1_prids AND  node2.PRID in p1_prids
```

but i think this is very inelegant and performance nightmare as it does the query twice - so still looking for a solution ...

What am i doing wrong in this query ? 
Is there a better way to approach this problem

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let me start over with a different answer for your new dataset (thanks for that, by the way, it was really helpful!)

The problem that I wasn't realizing was that the nodes that you want to match together will be in different results of the `p1` path because they're on either side of the start node.  So you could do something like this:

```
MATCH p1=(x:Organization {PRID: 'C'})-[r:CONTROL*]-(y)
WITH collect({path: p1, node: y}) AS paths_and_nodes
UNWIND paths_and_nodes AS paths_and_node1
UNWIND paths_and_nodes AS paths_and_node2
WITH
  paths_and_node1.node AS node1,
  paths_and_node2.node AS node2,
  paths_and_node1.path AS path1,
  paths_and_node2.path AS path2
MATCH p2=(node1)-[:EMPLOYS]->()-[:SPOUSE]->()-[:CONSULTS]->(node2)
RETURN path1, path2, p2, node1, node2
```

Or something like this which is a lot simpler:

```
MATCH
  p1=(org1)-[:CONTROL*]-(x:Organization {PRID: 'C'})-[:CONTROL*]-(org2),
  p2=(org1)-[:EMPLOYS]->()-[:SPOUSE]->()-[:CONSULTS]->(org2)
RETURN p1, p2, org1, org2
```

**EDIT**
So I think I see the problem.  I wasn't thinking about starting from any of the `Organization` nodes.  I'm pretty sure the second query will never work because Cypher will never hit the same node twice in a path.  So looking at the first query the reason it's not working with D and E is because the default `[*]` variable relationship definition is for one or more hops.  If we let it be zero or more hops then it seems to work:

```
MATCH p1=(x:Organization {PRID: 'C'})-[r:CONTROL*0..]-(y)
WITH collect({path: p1, node: y}) AS paths_and_nodes
UNWIND paths_and_nodes AS paths_and_node1
UNWIND paths_and_nodes AS paths_and_node2
WITH
  paths_and_node1.node AS node1,
  paths_and_node2.node AS node2,
  paths_and_node1.path AS path1,
  paths_and_node2.path AS path2
OPTIONAL MATCH p2=(node1)-[:EMPLOYS]->()-[:SPOUSE]->()-[:CONSULTS]->(node2)
RETURN path1, path2, p2, node1, node2
```

How's that?

Answer (score 0):

Let me give it a shot! ;)

So first off you can simplify your first `MATCH`/`WHERE` combo like this:

```
MATCH p1=(x:Organization {PID: '27762230'})-[r:`10006`|`10010`*]-(y)
```

So let's take that and try to do what you want:

```
MATCH p1=(x:Organization {PID: '27762230'})-[r:`10006`|`10010`*]-(y) 
WITH p1, nodes(p1) AS p1_nodes
UNWIND p1_nodes AS node1
UNWIND p1_nodes AS node2
WITH p1, node1, node2
OPTIONAL MATCH p2=(node1)-[:`10004`]->()-[:`10051`]->()-[:`10052`]->(node2)
WHERE p2 IS NOT NULL
RETURN p1, p2
```

It could also be that when you call `nodes(path)` that the objects that you get aren't nodes as much as `Map`s of the node properties.  If that's so we should be able to match via the IDs:

```
MATCH p1=(x:Organization {PID: '27762230'})-[r:`10006`|`10010`*]-(y) 
WITH p1, EXTRACT(node IN nodes(p1) | ID(node)) AS p1_node_ids
UNWIND p1_node_ids AS id1
UNWIND p1_node_ids AS id2
OPTIONAL MATCH p2=(node1)-[:`10004`]->()-[:`10051`]->()-[:`10052`]->(node2)
WHERE ID(node1) = id1 AND ID(node2) = id2 AND p2 IS NOT NULL
RETURN p1, p2
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, however it did not work for me. Couple of things (a) it was giving a syntax error at WHERE - i think you had put it to avoid the path p2 looping back to the same node - that is actually not what i need - so i removed it. However after removing it - I was getting no results back. I then changed the second MATCH to an OPTINAL MATCH - and after that it returns the sub-graph p1 but not p2 - even though in the data I have i do have data that meets that condition ...

Comment: one more thing i noticed in my tests - so in this query for path p2 we are trying to restrain both the starting and ending node of p2 to the set of nodes found in p1 - what i have observed is that if you only constrain one at a time - that is in your query above  in the lower MATCH if we change node1 to xxx or we change node2 to xxx, it shows p1 and p2 in the result ... but that is obviously not what we want - as our requirement is to Constrain both the starting and ending node to the set of nodes found in p1 ...

Comment: Good point about the `WHERE` and the `MATCH`.  I've edited to reflect those.  I'm not quite sure why the `OPTIONAL MATCH` isn't working.  I've edited with a couple of suggestions

Comment: thanks again for your suggestions Brian, unfortunately still no go, I am editing the post above with a simple Cypher script to test out this query so that you/someone can try it out easily ...

Comment: thanks for all your help, i tried the queries you provided - they work for some conditions but not for all, as its hard to put the queries in comments i am updating my question with the results for the queries you provided in the last answer ...

Comment: Just updated the other question with a small change which I think will fix it

Comment: thanks brian! it works great now. I still need to read up to understand all the techniques used in this query, couple of things that I am trying to understand A) if you have an UNWIND in a statement - it is that whatever is following the UNWIND is executed for each element of the array - including the final RETURNS and the result of the query is sort of a UNION of all the RETURNS B) What are we achieving by UNWINDING the paths_and_nodes array twice with different names. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Regarding A) Yeah, basically.  `UNWIND` is a bit of a funny clause.  It takes your current result set and, given an array for one column of that result set, creates duplicates of each row for each element in the array.  You still have the array as a column (or perhaps I should say variable), but now you've added another which is each item for the array for each row

Comment: Regarding B) The double UNWIND matches each element in the array (in this case the nodes of the path) to every other element in the array.  So if your path is 5 nodes long you'll end up with 5 * 5 = 25 result rows so that we can compare each node in the path with every other node in the path